# How to abstract for callbacks?

Tags: javascript, callback

I was working on a [Codewars kata](http://www.codewars.com/kata/52b757663a95b11b3d00062d) with the following problem: take a string consisting of only words and spaces, and convert every even-indexed letter within a word to uppercase. I came up with a solution that works but doesn't involve string/array methods or callbacks:

```
function toWeirdCase(string) {
    var weirded = "";
    var indexCounter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var character = string[i];
        if (indexCounter % 2 === 0 && character != " ") {
            weirded += character.toUpperCase();
            indexCounter++;
        } else if (character != " ") {
            weirded += character;
            indexCounter++;
        } else {
            weirded += " ";
            indexCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    return weirded;
}
```

Not elegant, but it works. Then I looked at the "best practice" solution, a very elegant one:

```
function toWeirdCase(string) {
    return string.split(' ').map(function(word) {
        return word.split('').map(function(letter, index) {
            return index % 2 == 0 ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter.toLowerCase()
        }).join('');
    }).join(' ');
}
```

The question, for those who would come up with a solution similar to the latter, is: what is your thought process? How do you break up the problem into steps, and know how to stage/order the methods so that you come up with this kind of solution?

If it's second-nature to you now, might you remember the "a-ha" moments that helped you develop the skills to tackle callbacks when you were first learning?

TL;DR: I understand callbacks conceptually, but would like to know how to approach problems that have callback solutions using a methodical approach.

Comment: How about using a regex?

Comment: i  try to think about what i need, and what i need to do. then i work backwards.  in this case, i need words from a string, so i think "i need an array of words". then i think about the next step and it seems that i need an array of chars, and i need to know the index of each char to conditionally transform it. [].map gives me both a value and an index, bingo. i first hammer on a string literal word in the console until i fashion something that does the char-altering steps in a re-usable function with a (char,i) signature. once that works, the part about string to array of words is easy...

Comment: You don't need to think "how to solve this with a callback". You need to think [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). It's just mapping over the words in a sentence, for each of them mapping over the letters in the word, for each of them uppercasing it when its index is even.